# JavaFx jar file tableView style properties not working when creating jar?

Tags: css, javafx, jar, tableview, netbeans-7

I am using Netbeans to create a jar for my FX application , the application is running fine in the standalone jar . but style properties of  tableview column header and some fonts are not working .

I have made the table view transparent but there in the jar it comes in grey colour also the font changes.

[image: Application while running from Netbeans]

[image: Application when running from standalone jar]

Here is my CSS file in the application

```
.button {
-fx-font-size: 13.0px;
-fx-font-weight:bold;
-fx-base: #00a7d4;
-fx-background: #e5f3f6;
-fx-focus-color: #0093FF;
-fx-control-inner-background: #FFFFFF;
-fx-text-base-color: #FFFFFF;
-fx-background-color: transparent;
-fx-inner-border: linear-gradient(to bottom, derive(-fx-color,73.6%) 0%, derive(-fx-color,29.200000000000003%) 100%);
-fx-body-color: linear-gradient( to bottom, derive(-fx-color, 34.0%) 0%, derive(-fx-color, -18.0%) 100%);
-fx-background-insets: 0px;
-fx-border-radius: 10;
-fx-background-radius: 10;
-fx-border-color:black;
-fx-padding: 0.166667em 0.833333em 0.25em 0.833333em; /* 2 10 3 10 */
/*-fx-text-fill: -fx-text-base-color;*/
-fx-alignment: CENTER;
-fx-content-display: LEFT;
}

.button:focused {
-fx-color:#00a7d4;
-fx-background-color:transparent;
-fx-background-insets: -1.4, 0, 1, 2;
-fx-border-radius: 10;
-fx-background-radius: 10;;
}

.button:hover {
-fx-focus-color: #FF0000;
-fx-background-color: #b3ffb3;
-fx-border-radius: 10;
-fx-background-radius: 10;
}

.root {
 -fx-background-image: url("/images/back.jpg");
  -fx-background-radius: 10 ;

}

#AOLtable .table-cell{
    -fx-alignment: CENTER;
    -fx-font-weight:bold;
}

#back {          
    -fx-graphic: url("/images/Backward.png");
    -fx-graphic-text-gap : 10;
}

.tab-pane *.tab-header-background
{
-fx-background-color: transparent;
}

#Content{
  -fx-background-image: url("/images/back.jpg");
}
.table-view {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 10;
    -fx-alignment: center;
}
.table-view .column-header-background {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: transparent transparent rgba(255,255,255,0.3) transparent;
    -fx-border-width: 1;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-padding: 0 10 0 0;
}
.table-view .column-header, .table-view .filler {
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
}
.table-view .column-header .label {
    -fx-text-fill: firebrick;
    -fx-font-weight: bold;
}
.table-view .table-cell {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
    -fx-border-color: transparent;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-alignment: center;
}
.table-view  .table-row-cell:filled:selected:focused,
.table-view  .table-row-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}



.table-view .table-row-cell {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
   /* -fx-border-color:black;*/

}
```

Please help as I cannot figure out what is wrong .
As other components are working why only the tableView column header of javaFX is not working.

I tried adding the table view css file in tuw fxml itself instead of adding it from the java code but the problem persists, it is not an error but the css suffers a bit. I also made a demo app to see if this a app bug or something but that one also has the same appearance of the table view please help

[image: Project Structure]

Comment: I tried adding the table view css file in tuw fxml itself instead of adding it from the java code but the problem persists, it is  not an error but the css suffers a bit. I also made a demo app to see if this a app bug or something but that one also has the same appearance of the table view please help.

Comment: What does your project structure look like?

Comment: updated the structure in the question

Comment: How are you loading the css file?  If you are loading it programmatically, you should create an if statement that pops up an alert that tells you if the file loaded successfully.

Comment: What you should do is take that css file and put it into the exact same folder as your controller or that file that is trying to use it.

Comment: The css files is loading fine as other css that i have applied to the application is working fine, even the background is coming from the css. Only in the case of tableview css it just doesn't work

Comment: I have listed the css i use in the question, only the table view part with the header dosent work when making jar rest everything works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127401/discussion-between-sedrick-jefferson-and-rahul-singh).

Comment: on same os? have you tried different oses?

Comment: Yes the same problem just with the tableview css

Comment: You should check the JVM version which you are running the JAR outside de IDE. JavaFX changes a lot within each new JVM version.

Comment: It using java 1.8 inside as well as outside when running in as a stand alone app